# Default sudo group for Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

What is the proper name that Debian (or ubuntu) uses for the sudo users? So far it seems like it's probably one of these:

- *sudo*
- wheel
- admin
- root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the sudo and admin. Debian uses the sudo.

root is group to user root, not for other user.
wheel is FreeBSD way.

Comment: Then "sudo" it is.